# SSI IF Statement error

Tags: apache, xampp, wamp, ssi, server-side-includes

I am having troubles with the if statement of SSI. I have reinstalled OSes on two computers (**one with win7, the other with win8**) and installed **WAMP** on them. Then I have put my old projects in the folder. After I have opened the project where I'm using SSI if I get the following error message:

**[an error occurred while processing this directive]**

The problem is that when I open those files at work and my laptop I do not get this error missing.

After that I have switched to **XAMPP**, but get the same error again.

I am using the following statement:

```
<!--#if expr="$DOCUMENT_NAME = home.html"-->
<body class="home">
<!--#else-->
<body>
<!--#endif-->
```

And it seems to enter the if statement, because it puts the body class ".home", and after that comes the message.

Everything else, but the if statement works. I have separated my header.shtml and footer.shtml and the ssi loads them in the site. But when I use if - it breakes.

I don't think it is related, but in case - this how my .htaccess file looks like:

```
Options +Includes
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml .html .htm
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `SSILegacyExprParser on` to your .htaccess

Refer this [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_include.html#ssilegacyexprparser).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change the httpd.conf file as SSI is not turned on in Apache by default.

Find this section of the httpd.conf file

```
#
# Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
#
# To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
# (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
#
#AddType text/html .shtml
#AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

And change it to

```
#
# Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
#
# To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
# (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
#
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

Comment: Nope. It is already that way. The SSI itself is working, but the if statement causes trouble.