# switch case (or if else) to load a file with include in SSI and QUERY_STRING?

Tags: if-statement, include, ssi, server-side-includes

In PHP I can use switch case for using a simple function:

```
<?php
switch($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {

case 'example1':
include 'example1.php';
break;

case 'example2':
include 'example2.php';
break;

case 'example3':
include 'example3.php';
break;

default:
include 'example1.php';
break;
}
?>
```

But how look it for SSI?

**My not working example:**
(Note: SSI is working with my Apache ;-) )

```
<!--#if expr="$QUERY_STRING = 'example1'" -->
    <!--#include virtual="example1.html" -->
<!--#elif expr="$QUERY_STRING = 'example2'" -->
    <!--#include virtual="example2.html" -->
<!--#elif expr="$QUERY_STRING = 'example3'" -->
    <!--#include virtual="example3.html" -->
<!--#else -->
    <!--#include virtual="example1.html" -->
<!--#endif -->
```

**I get only an error message:**

```
[an error occurred while processing this directive]
```

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found following for .htaccess and my example works...

```
SSILegacyExprParser on
```

But exist a valid code without to use this snippet?

**Sources**:

- [SSI IF Statement error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27664903/2422690) in this forum
- [SSILegacyExprParser Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html#ssilegacyexprparser) on apache.org

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<!--#if expr="v('QUERY_STRING') = '/example1'" -->
```

You shouldn't need the legacy parser turned on for that.